# Windows command to get list of file extensions

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, filesystems, file-attributes

I need  a command to get distinct  extensions files inside a folder with the number of occurency of each extension.

So how can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do it with a PowerShell one-liner like this:

```js
powershell "$ext = @{}; gci *.* | %{ $ext[$_.Extension]++ }; $ext"
```

If using this in a .bat script, double the `%` sign.

---

In pure Batch, this is the simplest way I can think of:

```js
@echo off & setlocal

for %%I in (*.*) do (
    set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1
)

set ext[
```

Or condensed to a one-liner (still in a .bat script):

```js
@setlocal & @(for %%I in (*.*) do @set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1) & set ext[
```

Or directly from the cmd console:

```js
cmd /c ">NUL (@for %I in (*) do @set /a ext[%~xI] += 1) & set ext["
```

(The `cmd /c` there behaves like `setlocal` in a bat script, helping you avoid junking up your environment with useless variables.)

Comment: thank you the last command works for me but I need an iterative way I need all file extensions in sub-folders

Comment: @LamloumiAfif in the `.bat` methods, use `for /R` to recurse.  In the PowerShell method, just add the `-recurse` switch to the `gci` command.  To include hidden / system files, in batch use `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /s /b /a:-d')` etc.  In PowerShell, add the `-force` option to `gci`.

Comment: +1, No need for `ext[...]`. You can simply use `set /a "%%~xI+=1"`, and then use `set .` to see the results. Ideally you should put a `SETLOCAL` at the top. Also, it wouldn't hurt to clear any existing `.` or `ext[` vars with something like `for /f "delims==" %%V in ('set .') do set "%%V="`. Either way, this counting method will fail in the unlikely case that the extension contains a math operator like `+`, `-`, `^`, etc.

Comment: Oops, I was wrong. Using `%%~xI` as the variable name fails if the file has no extension :-(

Comment: Great answer, but unfortunately doesn't work if there are any folders containing dots (.) in the name, as the string following the dot will be counted as extension. Using `gci -File` should fix the issue.

Comment: @rojo when I replace ```for %%I ``` with ```for /R``` in the batch method, I get the error ```do( was unexpected at this time.```

Comment: @plast1cd0nk3y you might have better luck with `for /R %%I`

Comment: @rojo this worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution from [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/a/397959). Save this code inside a `.bat` file.

```
@echo off

set target=%~1
if "%target%"=="" set target=%cd%

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set LF=^


rem Previous two lines deliberately left blank for LF to work.

for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('dir /b /s /a:-d "%target%"') do (
    set ext=%%~xi
    if "!ext!"=="" set ext=FileWithNoExtension
    echo !extlist! | find "!ext!:" > nul
    if not !ERRORLEVEL! == 0 set extlist=!extlist!!ext!:
)

echo %extlist::=!LF!%

endlocal
```