# Batch list all file extension in a specific directory

Tags: batch-file

Using windows batch file, I am trying to echo a list of file extensions in a folder.
That will then be set as %var% and output to .txt file

```
@setlocal & @(for %%I in (*.*) do @set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1) & set ext[
```

from this post [Windows command to get list of file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44072096/windows-command-to-get-list-of-file-extensions)

My end game is I would like it to output like so

folder contents:

```
sample1.jpg
sample2.jpg
sample3.jpg
sample4.mp4
sample5.mp4
sample6.png
sample7.zip
sample8.zip
```

result:

```
.jpg, .mp4, .png, .zip
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, I hope I explained it clear enough

Comment: I've re-inserted the code and link as a post without code is likely to be ignored for lack of evidence of an attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already have defined a variable for each extension. Just use another `for /f` loop to concatenate the relevant part (the actual extension) of them:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (*) do @set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1 
for /f "tokens=2 delims=[]" %%a in ('set ext[') do set "var=%%a, !var!"
echo %var:~0,-2%
```

Comment: Thank you both so much, both did what I was asking, however Stephan's output exactly as desired.
Thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

```
@setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION&@(for %%I in (*.*) do @set /a ext[%%~xI] += 1&IF DEFINED ext[all]  (IF "!ext[all]!" equ "!ext[all]: %%~xI=!" SET "ext[all]=!ext[all]!, %%~xI") ELSE (SET "ext[all]= %%~xI"))&SET "ext[all]=!ext[all]:~1!"&set ext[
```

Why you want this all on one line, I've no idea.

Since you need to access the changed value of a variable within a loop, you need `delayedexpansion`. Note that <kbd>Space</kbd>.ext is appended each time a new extension is found, so there will be an extra space at the start of the list variable - hence the requirement to remove the first character before displaying the result.